# Enable the php_fileinfo extension?

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to post images in the image file format.
My Code:

```
public function store ()
{
    $data = request()->validate ([
        'caption' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required | image | mimes: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg | max: 2048'
    ]);

    dd (request()->all());
}
```

But an error appears:

> Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are
> available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?).

I learned on StackOverflow enable file info. Meanwhile, I made sure to turn it on and reset it.
My PHP version is `7.4 XAMPP 3.2.4.`

Thank you, everyone!

Comment: Yes, i have it enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed xampp which is not suitable for the php version so it failed to install the php_file extension. You just need:

```
B1: Uninstall current xampp.
B2: Reinstall xampp to match the PHP version.
B3: Turn on the appropriate utilities.
```

Hope this answer is of help to you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO31M.png)